# key in imported JSX tag vs fully written code

Tags: reactjs, key

I'm relatively new to React and is encountering a problem while studying.

Here's the tutorial page:
https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state

The page shows 3 files almost at the end as below
and my question comes up when merging App.js and Chat.js:

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Chat from './Chat.js';
import ContactList from './ContactList.js';

export default function Messenger() {
  const [to, setTo] = useState(contacts[0]);
  return (
    <div>
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} selectedContact={to}
        onSelect={contact => setTo(contact)}
      />
      <Chat key={to.id} contact={to} />
    </div>
  )
}

const contacts = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Taylor', email: 'taylor@mail.com' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Alice', email: 'alice@mail.com' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@mail.com' }
];
```

**ContactList.js**

```
export default function ContactList({selectedContact,contacts,onSelect{
  return (
    <section className="contact-list">
      <ul>
        {contacts.map(contact =>
          <li key={contact.id}>
            <button onClick={() => {onSelect(contact);}}>
              {contact.name}
            </button>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```

**Chat.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Chat({ contact }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  return (
    <section className="chat">
      <textarea value={text}  placeholder={'Chat to ' + contact.name}
        onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <button>Send to {contact.email}</button>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I understand  and  are different so that setting key different clears the textarea.

My question comes up when I merge App.js with Chat.js like below:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Chat from './Chat.js';
import ContactList from './ContactList.js';

export default function Messenger() {
  const [to, setTo] = useState(contacts[0]);

  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} selectedContact={to}
        onSelect={contact => setTo(contact)}
      />
      {/* <Chat key={to.id} contact={to} /> */}
      <section className="chat" key={to.id}>                       //// (1)
        <textarea value={text} placeholder={'Chat to ' + to.name}  //// (2)
          onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <button>Send to {to.email}</button>                        //// (3)
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}

const contacts = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Taylor', email: 'taylor@mail.com' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Alice', email: 'alice@mail.com' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@mail.com' }
];
```

I put key in (1), (2), and (3), separately or in combination, but none of them worked.
It appears same to using  separately, but works differently.
Can anyone explain why?

Comment: The `key` prop in JSX elements help React render only the necessary elements in an array. They are only needed when [rendering arrays](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components). Can you explain exactly what you mean by "none of them worked", what do you expect to happen? You are giving key props to elements which do not need them

Comment: @Rich KS, the `key` you are using inside ContactList is enough, and its rule is to be passed as prop to the parent element like it already is. The keys at your comment of *1* *2* *3* shouldn't be included

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I've mistaken the necessity of keys in contacts and textarea.